# Google Cloud Run Restarts after too many 500 responses?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I've been debugging an issue with 503 `Server Unavailable` errors and I think GCP Run is stopping the instance if my code returns too many 500 status code errors which then causes all the other requests to throw 503 `Server Unavailable` errors.

Will Google Cloud Run shut down an instance if it responds too many times with status code 500?

Comment: Can you share more details about what you're actually seeing in the logs? It is also worth taking a look at the [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#serving) tips from the docs

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However, if your code is crashing or throwing unhandled exceptions, that is considered a container failure and will be cold started. Edit your question with exact details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think this is what is happening.  I can't find anything on container failure causing a cold start in the docs, do you remember where you saw that?

Comment: @bhito I'm happy to share logs but I'm not sure what you need.  The logs show a lot of requests, some of them are status code 500, and then at some point, the server seems to shut down and all existing requests return a "Server Unavailable" error with status code 503.

Comment: Start with this document: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting